# Return relationship attribute in Cypher fluent query

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, fluent, neo4jclient

I have the following Neo4jClient fluent API query that is used to return localized text for Xbox games stored in my Neo4j database:

```
var localized = client.Cypher
       .OptionalMatch("(xb:`XboxProfile`)-[p:PLAYS]->(g:`XboxGame`)-[:LOCALE]->(l:`XboxGameLocalized`)")
       .Where((Xbox.Profile xb) => xb.GamerTag == xboxProfile.GamerTag)
       .AndWhere((Xbox.Localization.Game l) => l.Locale == locale)
       .Return((l, g, p) => new {
           Localized = l.As<Xbox.Localization.Game>(),
           Game = g.As<Xbox.Game>(),
           LastPlayed = p.As<DateTimeOffset>()
       })
       .Results.ToList();
```

On the `PLAYS` relationship, I have a `LastPlayed` attribute that is a `DateTimeOffset` that I would like to return in the query result set. Currently, `p.As<DateTimeOffset>` isn't working as expected. It doesn't parse the date and the date is returning as:
`0001-01-01T00:00:00Z`

What is the correct way to return relationship attributes/properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `p` in your query is an entire object (or bag), but you're not qualifying the property you want:

```
LastPlayed = p.As<DateTimeOffset>()
```

Because it can't deserialize an entire object into a `DateTimeOffset`, but it's not a nullable type, you're getting the default value.

You just need to describe the type of `p`, for the sake of IntelliSense:

```
public class PlaysPayload
{
    public DateTimeOffset LastPlayed { get; set; }
}
```

And then use this in the query, to address the property you want:

```
   .Return((l, g, p) => new {
       Localized = l.As<Xbox.Localization.Game>(),
       Game = g.As<Xbox.Game>(),
       LastPlayed = p.As<PlaysPayload>().LastPlayed  // <-- this line is different
   })
```

You do *not* need to use `Relationship<T>` or `RelationshipInstance<T>`.

Disclaimer: I'm typing this at 0630 in the morning, while in an airport, while they're calling my plane. I'm the author of Neo4jClient so it should be correct, but I haven't verified this specific solution.

Comment: Thanks Tatham! I know you're the author of Neo4jClient and I've seen your other great answers on Neo4jClient. Congrats for making it to 3000 rep!